# Mathematical proof of homeomorphism between n-sphere with one point removed and $(n-1)-\text{dimensional}$ euclidean space

Tags: general-topology

Could someone help me with the mathematical proof of homeomorphicity between an n-dimensional sphere (sphere made of points of Rn+1 which have distance 1 from the origin) with one point removed and euclidean space of $(n-1)$ dimensions for $n \geq 1$?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you aware of stereographic projection?

Comment: You probably mean $n$-dimensional sphere and $n$-dimensional euclidean space.

Comment: No, I am not aware much about it. But I just saw in a book that it is a function f(x1,..,xn+1)=1/(1-xn+1)*(x1,x2,...,xn)

Comment: By n-sphere I mean sphere made of points of Rn+1 which have distance 1 from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p = (0, 0, \ldots, 1)$ being the "north pole" (and the point we delete from $S^{n-1}$), define
$$
f(x) = x - \frac{x \cdot p}{x \cdot p - 1} p
$$
where $x$ is an arbitrary point of $S^{n-1}$ with $x \ne p$.

Then $f(x)$ lies in the plane orthogonal to $p$, i.e., the set of all vectors of the form $(u_1, \ldots, u_{n-1}, 0)$, which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ via the homeomorphism
$$
(u_1, \ldots, u_{n-1}) \mapsto (u_1, \ldots, u_{n-1}, 0).
$$

I leave it to you to show that $f$ is continuous and a bijection; the latter is relatively easy: you just compute the inverse explicitly.

Comment: Is isomorphic same as homeomorphic here? And by proving that this function is homeomorphic to Rn-1, how is it proven that sphere with one point removed is homeomorphic to Rn-1?

Comment: I've edited to make the homeomorphism explicit.

Comment: Thanks, but I wished to ask how this function f is related to a sphere with one point removed..

Comment: $f$ is defined for all points $x$ of $S^{n-1}$, except for the point $p$ (the "north pole"). That's a "sphere with one point removed."